# Confusion in "is being"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, passive-voice, present-tense

I know when to use **is being**. It means the event is currently happening.

I have a doubt whether that event already existed and is still happening or it's a new event and is currently happening.

Example - `"Changes are being recorded in registers"` ,

Now whether the `Changes` are started recording now only, 
or 
"`Changes`" are already recorded and still recording in registers.

I Hope , its clear now..

Please clarify

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Changes **are being** recorded in registers

As you wrote, "It means the event is currently happening."

That is all. From the statement alone you cannot know past or future activity.

Of course, this does not mean that "current" implies a moment in time. For example, the "changes" mentioned might take 15 minutes to complete, but this is still considered as the "present time", and is the normal situation when using *is/are being*.

Answer (score -2):

> He is being hit.
>
> He is being kicked.

That means the event is taking place.